# Field theory if no fundamental space-time

Tags: spacetime, field-theory, theory-of-everything

If there is no fundamental space-time, is the field concept also doomed? If so, how can we derive unified field theory in a background space-time if there is no background space-time or worst, no target spacetime on which fields are even defined?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is the topic of current research which is referred to as *background independent* approaches to quantum gravity. The most prominent example being loop quantum gravity (LQG).

Indeed, many people believe that ultimately our universe is solely governed by combinatoric structures and that the apparent continuum only arises by coarse graining of the underlying discrete theory. (A result along these lines has been achieved in 2+1-dimensional LQG. [1]) If this conjectured discreteness of spacetime were true, then the concept of fields varying smoothly over some background becomes meaningless. Instead what would be left to define are some quantities along the vertices, edges, faces, etc., of the underlying graph.

#### References

[1] A. Ashtekar, *Lectures on nonperturbative canonical gravity*